# Find string with "//" and replace from "//" up to the end

Tags: javascript, regex

Supposed my inlineDiv_num_text has a value of: `//abc`  it must be replaced to `@comment@`

and `abc   //cde` must be replaced to `abc   @comment@`

please fix the condition i did, it's not working

```
//WRAP INLINE COMMENTS
if(/[^]*//[^]*/g.test(inlineDiv_num_text)){
    inlineDiv_num_text = inlineDiv_num_text.replace(///[^]*/g, "@comments@");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape each `\`.  try changing your search regex to `/\\\\\S*/`

http://rubular.com/r/QH0Wwd2WNH

---

**note:** some languages require you to escape your `\` twice. one for the base language, and one for the regex.  so if the above doesn't work, you might need something along the lines of   `/\\\\\\\\\\S*/`

Comment: @Sam I am: ow, it must be // (comments) my fault

Comment: @fireflieslive, `\/\/` will match `//`.

Comment: @fireflieslive, okay... I can see that link in the above answer.  Why are you reposing it here?